# Dark Souls II on PC - Collector's Edition / Scholar Of The First Sin confusion

Tags: dark-souls-2

I haven't bought Dark Souls II so far because I wanted to beat the previous one first. Now that I'm pretty close to achieving that goal (phew!) I'm thinking about which edition to get. I'm playing on PC.

I had planned on getting the **Collector's edition** including the art book, map and Knight figure.

Now that the **Scholar Of The First Sin** (SOTFS) edition is out, I'm unsure. As far as I know, updating from Vanilla to SOTFS costs extra money, and there is no Collector's edition of SOTFS.

What are the major differences between the version and what are consequences of each buying decision (besides the obvious one of the latter not including the physical Collector's edition content)? What are my options regarding upgrading from Collector's edition to SOTFS? Are there other options I've overlooked?

Comment: This is straying awfully close to asking us which you should get.  I bet you'd get a better reception if you wanted to focus on what the differences are between the two versions.

Comment: @Frank, thanks. I've tried to make that a liitle more clear in my question.

Comment: We're pretty good at giving you an objective comparison of the differences between two products.  Asking us to give you more options that might meet your needs strays into shopping advice, and that's totally off-topic, I'm afraid.  But other than that, your question's looking much better.

Answer (score 1):

SOTFS has updated enemy locations throughout the game - this means some enemies have moved slightly in the world, or replaced with completely different enemies. Some of the loot has also moved (it still exists, but is in a different chest or world location).

The only other major difference between vanilla DSII and SOTFS is the DLC. Buying the base game will require buying the 3 DLC packages if you want to play them. They are all included in SOTFS.

Comment: There's also additional lore explanation in the form of the Scholar, as well as an additional boss.

Comment: After having played through both versions, SOTFS is definitely a better game.  There are some very important loot changes that opens up a lot more of the game much, MUCH earlier.